# Hotwire websocket connection failed for Rails6 + Nginx and Phusion Passenger 6.0.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

I'm trying to use Hotwire for Rails, it works perfectly with my development environment, but having issues with websocket connection after deploy to our UAT (staging) environment.

**Stack**

Ruby: 3.0.0

Rails: 6.0.3.5

Nginx: 1.14.1

Passenger: **Phusion Passenger 6.0.4**

**nginx.conf** on my Gateway server

```html
upstream myapp {
    server myapp.uat.mycompany.com.au:80;
}

server {
    server_name myapp.uat.mycompany.com.au;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapp;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /cable {
        proxy_pass http://active_migration;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
   }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.uat.mycompany.com.au/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.uat.mycompany.com.au/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = myapp.uat.mycompany.com.au) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name myapp.uat.mycompany.com.au;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**nginx.conf** on my app server

```html
server {
  server_name myapp.uat.mycompany.com.au;
  listen 80;
  underscores_in_headers on;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env uat;
  root /var/www/myapp/current/public;

  location /cable {
     passenger_app_group_name myapp_action_cable;
     passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
  }
}
```

**cable.yml**

```html
 development:
      adapter: redis
      url: <%= ENV.fetch("ACTION_CABLE_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/8" } %>
      channel_prefix: myapp

    test:
      adapter: test

    uat:
      adapter: redis
      url: <%= ENV.fetch("ACTION_CABLE_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/8" } %>
      channel_prefix: myapp

    production:
      adapter: redis
      url: <%= ENV.fetch("ACTION_CABLE_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/8" } %>
      channel_prefix: myapp
```

**uat.rb** (environment configuration file)

```html
config.action_cable.url = 'wss://myapp.uat.mycompany.com.au/cable'
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['https://myapp.uat.mycompany.com.au', 'http://myapp.uat.mycompany.com.au']
```

**Errors displayed in Chrome console**

```html
connection.js:70 WebSocket connection to 'wss://myapp.uat.mycompany.com.au/cable' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

**Errors in uat.log**

```html
I, [2021-10-29T15:13:33.876173 #668]  INFO -- : [25f60292-8a89-4ce5-9f35-fb3ad56bef00] Started GET "/cable" for 10.1.32.123 at 2021-10-29 15:13:33 +1100
I, [2021-10-29T15:13:33.876890 #668]  INFO -- : [25f60292-8a89-4ce5-9f35-fb3ad56bef00] Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 10.1.32.123 at 2021-10-29 15:13:33 +1100
I, [2021-10-29T15:13:33.876966 #668]  INFO -- : [25f60292-8a89-4ce5-9f35-fb3ad56bef00] Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
E, [2021-10-29T15:13:33.877255 #668] ERROR -- : [25f60292-8a89-4ce5-9f35-fb3ad56bef00] WebSocket error occurred: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
E, [2021-10-29T15:13:33.878046 #668] ERROR -- : WebSocket error occurred: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
E, [2021-10-29T15:13:34.234885 #668] ERROR -- : WebSocket error occurred: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
E, [2021-10-29T15:13:36.397514 #20846] ERROR -- : WebSocket error occurred: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

Note: the above WebSocket error keeps happening ...

I googled around and found someone had the similar problem, so tried with the solution of
commenting out the **config.action_cable.url** in the **uat.rb** environment file and put **action_cable_meta_tag** in the **application.html.slim** file, but it didn't work.

I've spent lots of time with it, could someone shed some light on this please?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in my production environment. The only difference I can see is that the passenger version is Phusion Passenger 6.0.4 in my production env.

Will try to upgrade my staging passenger version

Comment: It would be better to edit this fact into your question, or even leave it as a comment on your own question.

Comment: @ouflak except that this is potentially the answer to the question "why is it not working?"